# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax. Password change script

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website for a university assignment and i have run into a snag while writing some PHP for email address and password change and this error has come up and i can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

Error code:
Failed to run query3: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username = chris' at line 1

```
    <?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: login.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 

$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //check for valid email
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $emailInvalid = true;
        $emailInvalidAmmount = 1;
        goto here;
    }
    //Check if the new E-mail matches existing E-mail address, if it does no action is needed
    if($_POST['email'] !=$_SESSION['user']['email'])
    {
        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email";
        $query_params = array (':email' => $_POST['email']);

        try
        {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            die("Failed to run query1: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        }

    //retrieve results and check if new E-mail address exists in the database
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {
        $emailExists = true;
        $emailExistsAmmount = 1;
    }
    }
    $query ="SELECT password, salt FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $query_params = array(':username' => $username);
    try 
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {
        die("Failed to run query2: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['currentPassword'] . $row['salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        }

        if($check_password == $row['password'])
        {
            $password_ok = true;
        }

        if($password_ok = true)
        {
            $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
            $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];
            if($newPassword == $confirmPassword)
            {
                $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
                $password = hash('sha256', $_newPassword . $salt);
                for($round = 0; $round <65536; $round++)
                {
                    $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
                }
                $query ="INSERT INTO users (password, salt) VALUES (:password, :salt)";
                $query .= "WHERE username = $username";
                $query_params = array(':password' => $password, ':salt' => $salt);
                try
                {
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                }
                catch(PDOException $ex)
                {
                    die("Failed to run query3: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
                }
            }
        $passwordChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `"WHERE username = $username"` You have a SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: The error message explains what the problem is, your SQL statement is incorrect.

Comment: that doesn't really help all that much. I knew that already, i just don't know what's wrong about it

Comment: Take a look at SLaks comment and put it together with the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for an assignment, I'll be vague.  Make sure you're properly parameterizing all of the variables you're including in all of your queries.